# beamer not compiling on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use Beamer in Latex. As a simple test, I tried to compile the TeXStudio template for Beamer
Here is the output
But to my surprise even after all of this it produced a pdf file????
thanks

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.6.27)  2 AUG 2022 06:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**btemp.tex
(./btemp.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2022/01/21 v3.65 A class for typesetting presentations
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/home/brian/texmf/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count185


! LaTeX Error: Command \AtBeginEnvironment already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1752   \csgappto{@begin@#1@hook}}
                                   
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\begin' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AtBeginEnvironment' will not work.


! LaTeX Error: Command \AtEndEnvironment already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1766   \csgappto{@end@#1@hook}}
                                 
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\end' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AtEndEnvironment' will not work.
```

Comment: remove the local etoolbox.sty, that is outdated